# Оператор REPLACE

Tags: php, mysql

Этот оператор расходует id. То есть, он если находит строку - удаляет и добавляет новую (получается id++).

При 500 000 пользователях, и 10 изменений их профиля - id будут больше 5 млн. Это ведь не правильно.

Но я читал в одном [блоге](http://recens.ru/mysql/32_tips_to_speed_up_mysql.html)

> Не используйте REPLACE (который на деле является DELETE + INSERT и расходует ID'ы): используйте вместо этого INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (то есть INSERT + UPDATE, если произошел конфликт). Эта же техника может использоваться, когда вам сначала нужно сделать SELECT, чтобы узнать, есть ли уже данные в базе, и затем выбрать INSERT или UPDATE. Зачем решать самому - положитесь на базу данных!

Я не понял как это реализовать. В данный момент у меня один запрос, создает и удаляет строки. Мне нужно сделать это же, но чтобы он создавал и изменял уже созданные, а не удалял и создавал заново.

Comment: Как оказалось, автоикримент то и не нужен мне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пример на оф.сайте](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Желательно прочитать более общую инфу [там же](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html).

В частности почти в самом конце:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY
> UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
> would cause a duplicate value in a
> UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE
> of the old row is performed. The
> affected-rows value per row is 1 if
> the row is inserted as a new row and 2
> if an existing row is updated.

Comment: Хм... Сам не до конца прочитал... По первой ссылке так же об этом сказано: "With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated."

Comment: Я посмотрел, и понял - мне нужен id. Поэтому, я просто удалю его и все. Вопрос можно считать исчерпанным.