# Как сделать UPDATE, а при отсутствии записи - INSERT?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Цель такая: если запись с таким `id` есть, тогда делаем инкремент значения в столбце `count` этой строки, а если же нет, то создаём новую запись (у столбца `count` задан `DEFAULT 0`). База данных - MySQL.

Конечно, можно сделать несколько проверок и реализовать такую логику через условия в самом языке программирования, но можно ли осуществить всё это одним SQL запросом (чтобы работало быстро), или, по крайней мере, сделать как-то изящнее?

Comment: Дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/185833/186083 или http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448488/186083

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`) VALUES (123456)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
```

Comment: `UPDATE` произойдет именно к записи, у которой `id`=123456?

Comment: UPDATE выполняется в случае, если при INSERT будет выявлено нарушение уникальности любого уникального индекса. При этом будет выполнено UPDATE именно той записи, наличие которой вызвало нарушение уникальности. Если вставляемые данные будут нарушать требование уникальности нескольких индексов, сработает ограничение того индекса, который в структуре таблицы имеет наименьший идентификатор.