# Обновление записи вместо создания новой при наличии записи с таким значением поля

Tags: php, mysql

Как организовать проверку условий при добавлении записи в БД?

Если в БД уже есть похожее имя, то вместо того чтобы добавлять новую строку (дублировать), просто обновить некоторые значения первой.

Предположим, что в БД есть 3 столбца (ид, имя, дата). Мне нужно, чтобы при записи новых строк шла проверка: к примеру, раз есть строка с именем "bla-bla", то не создавать новое "bla-bla" с новым ид, а просто поменять дату в первом "bla-bla" на новую и всё.

Было `('100', 'bla-bla', '08.01.2016 10:00')`

Стало `('100', 'bla-bla', '08.01.2016 10:47')`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/185833/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-replace и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448488/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b0

Comment: Какой великий смысл в существовании поля `ид` (вероятно, синтетический первичный ключ-автоинкремент?), если есть заведомо уникальное (если верить собственно формулировке вопроса) поле `имя`? И есть ли смысл обновлять данные, заведомо теряя историю изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, date) VALUES (100, 'bla-bla', '08.01.2016 10:47')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = '08.01.2016 10:47';
```

Также необходимо добавить `UNIQUE` индекс (или `PRIMARY KEY`) для поля `name`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сделал как вы посоветовали, но столкнулся с проблемой, у меня в VALUES передаются данные через переменные, и если писать с переменными VALUES ('".$item"', "'date"'....) то ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE становится не активным. А если писать VALUES ('123', '12122015') то все окей.  Может быть я что-то не так делаю..пересмотрел все ссылки которые мне дали в ответах, вроде все правильно, а все равно не работает и не могу понять почему

Comment: @ВладимирВ. проверьте как у вас выглядит запрос после конкатенаций в коде. В `VALUES ('".$item"', "'date"'....)` мне кажется весьма подозрительным отсутствие точки по `$item`, а также `"'date"'` вместо `'" . $date . "'`. Но к самому вопросу это, вообще говоря, уже не относится.

Comment: В самом файле у меня есть точки .$date. , .$item. Я допустил ошибку и не дописал их при написании ответа вам.

Comment: @ВладимирВ. сохраните текст запроса в переменную, выведите её на экран и проверьте на ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Можно таким образом, все работает как надо

```
INSERT INTO requests ('user_id','subject','text','time') 
VALUES (56,'test','test 1234',6516516)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = VALUES(time), user_id = VALUES(user_id)
```